How merge everything into origin/master and get rid of origin/main?
I have a git repo backed by a BitBucket instance. In this repo I appear to have three branches:

main (my local branch I guess)
origin/master
origin/main

The master naming scheme seems to be the standard on our BitBucket instance, so I want to adhere to this and end up having only

master (my local branch)
origin/master

How do I get rid of the origin/main branch and rename my local main to master?

Note that there is nothing special about a branch named master to git. You may have protection rules on bit bucket for branch named main, check the settings of that repo through bit bucket gui.

Renaming local branch: git branch -m master. Checking your history your favorite GUI viewer for git, or git log --graph --oneline master origin/master origin/main. Merge histories as you wish, then git push origin -u master:master. Delete remote main: git push -d origin main

This question is probably a duplicate, will look for matching question when I have time. In the meantime, hope you found your information.

git branch --remotes --delete origin/main && git remote prune origin via Jakub
